# How to pass values to array then loop through a data set

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, dynamic

I'm trying to build a loop to sum 200 consecutive rows (or a number of rows determined from an input box) from Column E, then move the range down one cell and recalculate (loop) until it has gone through all the used cells in the named worksheet.

the length/size of the Array is static for the purposes of the loop, it is requested from the user via an inputbox and is to remain the same until the loop is completed.

So far I have completed the calculation once using static cell references eg. "E2:E201" shown below:

```
ClosingPrice200Array = Range("E2:E201").Value
```

So i know the code can calculate the Sum of the range and divide by a variable.

The problems I'm having include:

1. I want to sum the next 200 consecutive rows from E3:E202, then E4:E203 etc all the way down to the last used row without naming every change of range.

To do this I have declared row variables, confirmed I have counted the correct number of rows and attempted to pass the first range (E2:E201) to the named array using row variables however I am getting a "Compile error: Can't assign to Array" from my code:

```
Sub Calculate200DMA()

    Dim Dma200current As Double
    Dim SumLast200Days As Long
    Dim MovingAverageLength As Integer
    MovingAverageLength = Application.InputBox("Input Required", "Moving Average Length", 200, , , , , 1)
    Dim ClosingPrice200Array(MovingAverageLength) as Variant
```

'can't remember if an array size needs to be a constant but I can create other array variables to cater for that in need, so please advise if I cannot dynamically adjust the Array size each time it runs the macro.

```
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
Dim NumberOfRows As Long

'count number of rows to be used in the For loop
Sheets("Data processing").Select
NumberOfRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

FirstRow = 2
CurrentRow = FirstRow + (MovingAverageLength - 1)
Lastrow = CurrentRow
```

'this is the row causing the compile error:

```
ClosingPrice200Array = Sheets("Data processing").Range(Cells(FirstRow, 5), Cells(Lastrow, 5)).Value
```

'the rest seems to work correctly in terms of calculating the number i want:

```
SumLast200Days = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ClosingPrice200Array)
Dma200current = SumLast200Days / MovingAverageLength
Sheets("Data processing").Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Value = Dma200current

'then i want to increment to the For loop but i have not written the start nor end loop yet because not sure exactly how to write (have been googling how to populate the array first)
FirstRow = FirstRow + 1
Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
```

2. Also the input box is not appearing to prompt input of the length (number of rows) for the range. This is my code for the input box:

   `Dim MovingAverageLength As Integer
   MovingAverageLength = Application.InputBox("Input Required", "MovingAverageLength", 200, , , , , 1)`

Thank you in advance for helping. Could not find exactly something which solved the problem in my google searches (here or elsewhere) so far.

John

Comment: `Dim ClosingPrice200Array as Variant` - just declare it as a Variant, not an array of variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use `WorksheetFunction.Average()` function and work with ranges:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate200DMA()
    Dim MovingAverageLength As Long, LastRow As Long
    MovingAverageLength = Application.InputBox("Input Required", "Moving Average Length", 200, , , , , 1)

    Dim FirstRow As Long, CurrentRowOffset As Long, LastRowOffset As Long

    FirstRow = 2
    With Sheets("Data processing")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowOffset = (LastRow - FirstRow + 1) - MovingAverageLength ' set the last offset from first row
        With .Cells(FirstRow, 4).Resize(MovingAverageLength) ' reference the first range to sum
            For CurrentRowOffset = 0 To LastRowOffset
                .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Offset(CurrentRowOffset))
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to assign variables in the For loop and an operator - are there restrictions in loops?

`Dma200current = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Offset(CurrentRowOffset))
                
                .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 2).Value = YesterdaysOpen
                .Cells(.CurrentRowOffset - 1, 3).Value = YesterdaysHigh
'the above are to assign values to these variables on the current row
                .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 5).Value = Dma200current                 
                .Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(CurrentRowOffset, 6).Value = DMASlopeCurrent`

Comment: the above variables have been declared as 'Double' at the start of the sub as the same type as the Dma200current which i will compare them to. Can a loop only have one data type? Have tried declaring them all as 'Long' but didn't see to work. 

I am trying to compare yesterday's data to today, perform some operations and then assign the result to a variable, then assign the value of a cell on the spreadsheet to that variable (in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify *all your objects* to your worksheet when setting the range for your array.

So replace this line:

```
ClosingPrice200Array = Sheets("Data processing").Range(Cells(FirstRow, 5), Cells(Lastrow, 5)).Value
```

With

```
With Worksheets("Data processing")
    ClosingPrice200Array = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 5), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value
End With
```

Also, ensure that you are declaring your array as type **Variant** as stated by [Tim William's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891047/how-to-pass-values-to-array-then-loop-through-a-data-set/49891314#comment86798079_49891047).

---

Editing in response to [OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891047/how-to-pass-values-to-array-then-loop-through-a-data-set/49891314?noredirect=1#comment86836902_49891314):

> can you please advise why you used the with instead?

You are *never required* to use a `With...End With` statement. This statement simply makes your code more readable and also can save some keystrokes.

If you didn't use the with statement, you would have had to type out your `Worksheets("Data processing")` three times in that line:

1. Worksheets("Data processing").Range()
2. Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(firstRow, 5)
3. Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(lastRow, 5)

This would make it less readable with this being the outcome:

```
ClosingPrice200Array = Worksheets("Data processing").Range(Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(firstRow, 5), Worksheets("Data processing").Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value
```

While the above works, it just makes sense **not to type out `Worksheets("Data processing")` three times**, but instead use the with statement.

The reason your code wasn't working is that you only qualified your `Range()` object to the worksheet, but not the `Cells()` objects within your `Range()`, which meant you were using the active sheet instead.

You can qualify objects inside a with statement by using placing a period `.` in front of the child objects.

Here's another example of using a With statement:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1") = "Blah"
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Blah"
    .Range("F:F").Clear
End With
```

If you didn't use the with statement, you would have had to type the worksheet out three times:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Blah"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Blah"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Clear
```

So again, it's optional but useful. You just needed to qualify both of your `Cells()` objects to the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your time. Just for my learning - to fully qualify all my objects you mean to tell excel exactly where the object (cells) are that I'm trying to manipulate, so I've omitted `Worksheets("Data processing")` and also omitted using the `With / End With` statement. Clearly there is a reason I need to use a `With` statement instead of just saying `ClosingPrice200Array = Worksheets("Data processing").Range(.Cells(firstRow, 5), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value`, can you please advise why you used the `with` instead? Just so I don't make the same mistake again. Thank you again!

Comment: See my edit. Hope that helps! Also, if either of these two answers that you were provided solved your problem, don't forget to mark one as accepted to let others know that you no longer need assistance.